# get model within onSubmit()

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to get the model, that current view has used for rendering, in the onSubmit() method?

I somehow want to "redirect the model" that was given to the current view from another controller by return

```
new ModelAndView("searchResults", "model", myModel)
```

Comment: i fyou want to change the view that controller returns just change the view name in return statement.

Comment: @NimChimpsky I need this view. It contains a button. By pressing it, i want another view with the same model.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a form reference any attribute and submit to any servlet/controller using something like :

Incldue tags

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

create url var

```
<c:url var="myURL" value="/ANywhere/whatever" />
```

define form something like

```
<form:form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="${myUrl}" method="POST" modelAttribute="yourAttribue">
<form:input path="firstname" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
The model I want to redirect was given to the current view from another controller by `return new ModelAndView("searchResults", "model", myModel)`

Comment: you want to submit every attribute in the current view and to another controller ? Usign term redirect is a bit confusing, you do that server side ' return "redirect:myOtherView"; '